# getting a node value with its parents name

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

```
<root>    
<helmets>
        <enduro>
            <front>
                <frames>
                    <item>
                        <![CDATA[assets/helmet.jpg]]>
                    </item>
                </frames>
                <buttons>
                    <item>
                        <![CDATA[assets/helmet.jpg]]>
                    </item>
                </buttons>
            </front>
            <side>
                <frames>
                    <item>
                        <![CDATA[assets/helmet.jpg]]>
                    </item>
                </frames>
                <buttons>
                    <item>
                        <![CDATA[assets/helmet.jpg]]>
                    </item>
                </buttons>
            </side>
        </enduro>
    </root>
```

For example i selected an item;

```
XML.children().children().children().children()[0]; //assets/helmet.jpg
```

How can i get name of parent node? For this example i wanna know its parent like;
item > frames > front > enduro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very inconvenient and error prone way to get data from an XML instance.

```
package {

  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.text.TextField;

  public class XMLExample extends Sprite {

    public function XMLExample() {

      const data:XML =
          <root>
            <helmets>
              <enduro>
                <front>
                  <frames>
                    <item>
                      <![CDATA[assets/helmet.jpg]]>
                    </item>
                  </frames>
                </front>
              </enduro>
            </helmets>
          </root>;

      const list:XMLList = data..item,
          parentName:String = list[0].parent().name(),
          textField:TextField = new TextField();

      textField.text = parentName;
      addChild(textField);
    }
  }
}
```

This would be the simple example. Of course you should access certain data via methods.